# integer type long and division

Tags: c, long-integer, division

I just write a procedure to decompose an unsigned integer to prime numbers. it will work normally if I define the data type as "**int**", if I change it to "**long**", result will be wrong. I don't know why.

BTW, I used Win-TC as my compiler.

Code as below:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define True    0xff
#define False   0x00
char DividerIsPrime(unsigned long data);
void CheckIfDataCanBeExtracted(unsigned long data);
main()
{
    unsigned long data;
    printf("please input data:");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    printf("\n%d=",data);
    CheckIfDataCanBeExtracted(data);
//    printf("%d",sizeof(short));
    getch();
}

void CheckIfDataCanBeExtracted(unsigned long data)
{
    unsigned long divider,temp,data1;
    data1=data;
    for(divider=2;divider<=data;divider++)
    {
         temp=data1%divider;
         if(temp) {continue;  }
         if(DividerIsPrime(divider)) {
        data1 = data1/divider;
        printf("%d",divider);
        if(data1==1) break;

        else {printf("*");  divider--;}


      }
    }
    return;

}

/* Check if this number is a prime number */
char DividerIsPrime(unsigned long data)
{
    unsigned long divider;
    char    status=True;
    for(divider=2;divider<data;divider++)
    {
        if(data%divider) status=True;
        else status=False;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Thanks for Paul's help, I know where is wrong. %d should be replaced by %ld.

Comment: What is the result? How is it wrong?

Comment: first, please format your code correctly, this is barely readable.
then don't use `char` as truth values, in C89 you should always use `int` and no bogus constants: I have never yet seen somebody use 255 for true, wow. But to come to the point, you didn't tell us what and how this fails.

Comment: If I input data=4, then it output4=2*2*3*1597*-21753;
I print the data1/divider, its result is a negative number..but I defined it as "unsigned".

Comment: You need to fix your `printf` and `scanf` - for unsigned long it needs to be `%ld`.

Comment: @Paul:Thank you...I learnt %ld...Now it can work perfectly~~

Comment: @Celia Zou: note that while `%ld` will work, it should really be `%lu` (u for unsigned).

Answer (score 1):

Your function `DividerIsPrime`,as currently written, has the defect that logically it must always return `True`.

The reason for this is that status is changed at each iteration.  Even if `status=False` is reached (the number is composite because the modulus came out zero for a divider), then the iterations will continue and in every case, `status=True` will be reached on the final iteration when *divider == (data - 1)*.

You can change this as follows:

```
/* Check if this number is a prime number */
char DividerIsPrime(unsigned long data)
{
    unsigned long divider;
    for(divider=2;divider<data;divider++)
    {
        if (0==(data % divider))
            return False;
    }

    return True;
}
```

You would have found this with some "unit test" such as:

```
assert(DividerIsPrime(5));
assert(!DividerIsPrime(6));  /* This test would fail without corrected code. */
```

Obviously there are much more efficient algorithms for "primality testing".

Comment: However, this defect should have been apparent with ints. Wonder why the poster thought the int/long difference was important.

Comment: I changed the function you mentioned. but its result remails fail.

Comment: Do you understand how the original function was incorrect and why?  It sounds like you are only taking my word for the truth.